# Using a Kalman filter to predict samples between measurements

Tags: c++, kalman-filter

I have a dataset where measurements were taken at 10 Hz, and I am trying to use a Kalman filter to add predicted samples in between the measurements, so that my output is at 100 Hz. I have it working ok when the velocity is linear, but when the direction changes, the filter takes a while to catch up. I am new to Kalman models, so am very likely making some mistakes in my settings. See [attached image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4RPGA-5qhz0OE5HY3pIR1VBdTN5WU1FTlZsc3B2LU4zS240/view) for an example, the red is measured data, with stepping in between measurements. The blue is the Kalman corrected.

`std::vector<double> measurements` is a dummy data array I am testing with.

The main Kalman code is based on [Github: hmartiro/kalman-cppkalman.cpp](http://Github:%20hmartiro/kalman-cppkalman.cpp)

The measurement / estimation loop is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702120/how-to-use-a-kalman-filter-to-predict-gps-positions-in-between-meassurements)

Am I correct in feeding the prediction back into the filter for every loop? Or is this line:

`yPos << kf.state().transpose();` wrong?

My code is:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  int n = 3; // Number of states
  int m = 1; // Number of measurements

  double dt = 1.0/10; // Time step

  Eigen::MatrixXd matA(n, n); // System dynamics matrix
  Eigen::MatrixXd matC(m, n); // Output matrix
  Eigen::MatrixXd matQ(n, n); // Process noise covariance
  Eigen::MatrixXd matR(m, m); // Measurement noise covariance
  Eigen::MatrixXd matP(n, n); // Estimate error covariance

  // Discrete motion, measuring position only
  matA << 1, dt, 0, 0, 1, dt, 0, 0, 1;
  matC << 1, 0, 0;

  // Reasonable covariance matrices
  matQ << 0.001, 0.001, .0, 0.001, 0.001, .0, .0, .0, .0;
  matR << 0.03;
  matP << .1, .1, .1, .1, 10000, 10, .1, 10, 100;

  // Construct the filter
  KalmanFilter kf(dt,matA, matC, matQ, matR, matP);

  // List of noisy position measurements (yPos)
  std::vector<double> measurements = {
     10,11,13,13.5,14,15.2,15.6,16,18,22,20,21,19,18,17,16,17.5,19,21,22,23,25,26,25,24,21,20,18,16
  };

  // Best guess of initial states
  Eigen::VectorXd x0(n);
  x0 << measurements[0], 0, 0;
  kf.init(dt,x0);

  // Feed measurements into filter, output estimated states
  double t = 0;
  Eigen::VectorXd y(m);


  for(int i = 0; i < measurements.size(); i++) { //ACTUAL MEASURED SAMPLE

      yPos << measurements[i];

      kf.update(yPos);

      for (int ji = 0; ji < 10; ji++)  // TEN PREDICTED SAMPLES
      {
          t += dt;       

         kf.update(yPos);


          yPos << kf.state().transpose(); //USE PREDICTION AS NEW SAMPLE

      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: This question might find more traction at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ah, i will move it there. Thank you!

Comment: @AndyG The question has been [downvoted and closed on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/165277/9357).

Comment: @200_success: Apologies for my naivete. I thought that Code Review would be a good spot following the guidance [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users), specifically that "Answers can suggest any improvement". I (incorrectly) assumed that OP thought that their code was working for most cases, but was looking for feedback on perhaps any edge cases where it would fail.

Comment: Can't seem to find a home for this. I will get the code working and re-write the question. Should I close this one? or will that effect my 'reputation'? Thanks!

Comment: You might be interested in these answers:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290860/tracking-position-and-velocity-using-a-kalman-filter/34324218#34324218
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702120/how-to-use-a-kalman-filter-to-predict-gps-positions-in-between-meassurements/26263172#26263172